# ¿Cómo verificar en Delphi si tengo una versión de Windows Server o no?

Tags: windows, delphi

Estoy intentando evaluar si tengo o no una versión de Windows Server en Borland Delphi 7, he encontrado algunas preguntas similares pero no me han funcionado

[How to check in delphi the OS version? Windows 7 or Server 2008 R2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268178/how-to-check-in-delphi-the-os-version-windows-7-or-server-2008-r2)

[Getting the Windows version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144599/getting-the-windows-version)

y me da un problema con `wProductType` que debería venir de `OSVERSIONINFO` pero al parecer esta propiedad no existe en esta clase `Windows.pas`

```
function WindowsServer:Boolean;

var data: OSVERSIONINFO;
begin
   data.dwOSVersionInfoSize := sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO);
   if(GetVersionEx(data)) and (data.dwPlatformId = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT) and (data.dwMajorVersion = 6) then
      begin
          case data.dwMinorVersion of
            0: if data.wProductType <> VER_NT_WORKSTATION then
                result := true;
            1: if data.wProductType <> VER_NT_WORKSTATION then
                result := true;
            2: if data.wProductType <> VER_NT_WORKSTATION then
                result :=true;
          end;
      end
end;
```

El problema que tengo es:

`[Error] Project1.dpr(18): Undeclared identifier: 'wProductType'`

Puedo implementar esto con `OSVERSIONINFOA` o `OSVERSIONINFOW`?

Answer (score 1):

La función GetVersionEx está marcada como obsoleta desde Windows 8.1, por lo que su uso a estas alturas no es recomendable, de la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getversionexa)

> GetVersionExA may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, use the Version Helper functions.

Mi traducción libre:

> GetVersionExA puede modificarse o no estar disponible para versiones posteriores a Windows 8.1. En su lugar, utilice las funciones del *Version Helper*.

Las [documentación de las funciones del *version helper*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/version-helper-apis) mencionado arriba nos indica que, dentro de otras, existe la [función `IsWindowsServer()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/versionhelpers/nf-versionhelpers-iswindowsserver) que sirve justamente para el propósito que buscas:

> Indicates if the current OS is a Windows Server release. Applications that need to distinguish between server and client versions of Windows should call this function.

Mi traducción libre:

> Indica si el sistema operativo actual es una versión de **Windows Server**. Las aplicaciones que necesitan distinguir entre las versiones de servidor y de cliente de Windows deben llamar a esta función.

Hay una traducción de este archivo a pascal realizada por JPeterMurgaas y liberada bajo licencia BSD/MPL, que puedes encontrar en github: [versionhelpers para Delphi](https://github.com/JPeterMugaas/versionhelpers). Con esta biblioteca, es tan simple como esto:

```
program DetectaServidor;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  versionhelpers;

begin
  if IsWindowsServer then
    Writeln('Estoy ejecutándome en un servidor')
  else
    Writeln('Estoy ejecutándome en un cliente');
  readln;
end.
```